# I get an error when I create a web application Listener

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, servlet-listeners

I get an error after creating a web listener in my java EE project , but whenever I delete it
and delete the listener tag from web.xml the app works again , I don't know what to do to resolve this problem , any ideas ?

The error is :

```
In-place deployment at C:\Users\Oday Alokeh\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WADLab02\build\web
GlassFish Server, deploy, null, false
C:\Users\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WADLab02\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1045: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: So what does the server log say?

Comment: errors like :

 Exception while loading the app ,,,
 Undeployment failed for context /WADLab02,,,
 Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.,,,
 Exception while invoking class com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication start method

Comment: You need to review the error log carefully, then identify the lines of code that are giving you trouble and then figure out why or ask here why, providing the code and the error log dump. Otherwise the best you can get is a generic answer, such as: check out this post on Java web app listeners see if you get what you are doing wrong: http://javaevangelist.blogspot.com/2013/11/java-ee-7-tip-of-day-web-application.html